# Finding a curve that is orthogonal at $(1,1)$ to the set of given parabolas

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, conic-sections, slope

I am given a DE like the following:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2xy}{x^2-1}$$

When one solves it:

$$y = A(x^2-1)$$

Then we obtain an equation for a family of parabolas all intersecting $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

I did not realise how to solve it so I looked up a solution, and what I had to do is invert the DE on the RHS and multiply it by $-1$ and then find constant by considering the fact that at $(1,1)$ that cruve should be orthogonal to the family of parabolas.

I am quite confused why I would have to swap the denominator and numerator:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{x^2-1}{2xy}$$

I know that if $m$ is slope then orthogonal tangents when multiplied would give $-1$: $m (-1/m) =-1$. And this fact must have something to do with my confusion.

EDIT: To clarify what I was asking there. I am given a DE which gives a family of parabolas when solved. I was then asked to to find a curve that is orthogonal to each of these parabolas at $(1,1) $. And I was confused why in the solution dy/dx was inverted to arrive at such a curve that is orthogonal to all parabolas at $(1,1)$.

I think I have just realised the answer as I was typing. $dy/dx$ is a general equation for the slope at any point in the domain. I have typed up too much now. I shall leave this in case someone else will benefit from this.

Comment: It isn't clear what your question really is. Consider editing the question to include one sentence ending in '?'

Comment: I think it is quite obvious if you read the title

Comment: I read your question title, but it's still unclear to me. Do you want to find the line perpendicular to the solutions of the ODE or do you want the explanation of how the ODE is solved?